# error message in coverting php html form in pdf using dompdf

Tags: php, html, dompdf

i am trying to convert my PHP/HTML form into pdf by using dompdf after clicking submit button. Everything was working fine but when I used for loop then following error occuered :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'servproname' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc\invoice.php

here is my php code

```
<?php
                       namespace Dompdf;
                    require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

              if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
               $dompdf = new Dompdf(); 
                $dompdf->loadHtml('
                   <html>
                    for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['servproname']);$i++) {
                  <table>
                <tr>
           <td style = "text-align:left; border:1px solid #cccccc;">'.$_POST['servproname'][$i].'</td>   
          <td style = "text-align:left; border:1px solid #cccccc;">'.$_POST['docname'][$i].'</td>
          <td style = "text-align:center; border:1px solid #cccccc;">'.$_POST['price1'][$i].'</td>
         <td style = "text-align:center; border:1px solid #cccccc;">'.$_POST['qty'][$i].'</td>
          <td style = "text-align:center; border:1px solid #cccccc;">'.$_POST['tot4'][$i].'</td>
                   </tr>
                          }
                      </table>
                         ');
                  $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
                   $dompdf->render();
                    $dompdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));
                  exit(0);
                }
             ?>
```

Comment: Why do you think `for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['servproname']);$i++)` would be run _inside a string_, without the `<?php` part? As already mentioned, concatenate your string first, then pass the resulting string to `loadHtml()`.

Comment: how  to concatenate string

Comment: PHP 101. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Seriously?? Are search engines banned in your location??? Type "php concatenate string" into a search engine. We're happy to help people here when necessary,  but we give our free time to this, so we are not a replacement for using your initiative, or doing really basic research.

Comment: Hint: you will need to put your string gradually into a variable, step by step, and then pass the finished variable to the loadHtml function

Comment: P.s. the precise reason for that specific error is because the `'` in `$_POST['` terminates the string which you also started with a `'`. But you can't put a loop inside a string and expect it to execute, regardless of that, hence our comments above about changing your approach.

Answer (score 3):

The way you are using syntax is totally wrong, using PHP in strings? when you open a ' or ", PHP recognizes that as a string not a code to interpret.
You should do something like this:

```
namespace Dompdf;
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $dompdf = new Dompdf();
   $tables = '';

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['servproname']); $i++) {
       $tables .= " <table>
           <tr>
               <td style=\"text-align:left; border:1px solid #cccccc;\">{$_POST['servproname'][$i]}</td>   
               <td style=\"text-align:left; border:1px solid #cccccc;\">{$_POST['docname'][$i]}</td>
               <td style=\"text-align:center; border:1px solid #cccccc;\">{$_POST['price1'][$i]}</td>
               <td style=\"text-align:center; border:1px solid #cccccc;\">{$_POST['qty'][$i]}</td>
               <td style=\"text-align:center; border:1px solid #cccccc;\">{$_POST['tot4'][$i]}</td>
           </tr>
       </table>";
   }
   $dompdf->loadHtml("<html> $tables </html>");
   $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
   $dompdf->render();
   $dompdf->stream("", array("Attachment" => false));
   exit(0);
}
```

As you can see i made a variable called **$tables** which is a string of what you where trying to make.